# Inserting vlookup via formular1c1 in a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to fill a Vlookup into a range of cells using .FormulaR1C1 and get an error 1004. I have almost this exact code elsewhere in my macro and it works fine so I'm not sure what's wrong. It's probably a simple fix and I'm just not seeing it...

Here is the code:

```
Range("W2").Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],$AA$2:$AC$35,3,TRUE)"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Be sure that all of your code is formatted correctly so that it makes it easier to read. (Your first line is off)  Provide a complete verifiable example. In this case you have provided a formula with various references, but I don't know what that data should be. I also don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so it's difficult to compare with the rest of your macro.

Comment: Thanks, @CodyG. Will do so moving forward. It looks like Scott Craner answered below. (Thanks to YowE3K for doing some initial edits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use R1C1 then all references must be in that format.

```
Range(Range("W2"), Range("W2").End(xlDown)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],R2C27:R35C29,3,TRUE)"
```

But you should always apply the parentage of the sheet to each range object:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
    .Range(.Range("W2"), .Range("W2").End(xlDown)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],R2C27:R35C29,3,TRUE)"
End With
```